# Nullreference in Global in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on ASP.NET project and I need to initialize my application with some data from DB.

I ll store it in Application[KEY], so I implement some class called DatabaseApplication. Then I want to call it just only once when whole application is starting. So I decided to write call from Application_Start method.

It's bad idea, becuase it ll throw exception

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
> WebformApp.dll but was not handled in user code...

in class <> Application (it's null)

## global

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup

            // Initialization of Session basics
            Application["UsersOnline"] = 0;

            // Inicjalizacja danych
            DatabaseApplication databaseApplication = new DatabaseApplication();
            databaseApplication.InitializeApplicationData();

        }
```

## class <>

```
public class DatabaseApplication : Page
    {
        private Procs Container;

        public DatabaseApplication()
        {
            Container = new Procs();
        }

        public void InitializeApplicationData()
        {
            if (Application["CourrierEnvoyeList"] == null)
            {
                InitList();
            }
        }

        private void InitList()
        {
            Application["List"] = Container.GetList().ToList();
        }
    }
```

is there any smarter solution?

Comment: `Application_Start` is triggered only once for the full lifetime of the application whereas ASP.NET maintains  a   pool of `HttpApplication` objects (similar to the ADO.NET connection-pool). [**MSDN:**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29) _"You should set only static data during application start. Do not set any instance data because it will be available only to the first instance of the HttpApplication class that is created."_

Comment: @TimSchmelter This doesn't apply here, because the `Application` property is actually shared across all the requests, it's not an instance field on the `HttpApplication`-derived class. Although I'm not sure if the value is guaranteed to be stored until the application restarts. It might be better to use some lazy-initialization instead.

Comment: Lazy-initialization - for example when you are trying to get something from database for first time and it doesn't exist in Application content -> you just get it and share with Application, so next time it will be loaded from Application instead again from DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, be careful about what you do in `Application_Start` and similar methods - lots of stuff you take for granted aren't there yet.

For your case, I'd try this:

1. Don't try creating a `Page` instance. Instead, separate the data layer from the UI page, and create that in `Application_Start`.
2. Pass the application instance (`this` in `Application_Start`) to the init method as a parameter. You should then be quite capable of setting the application-wide setting data.

Also, take care with such application-spanning objects. It's very easy to run into concurrency issues with global objects. This shouldn't be a problem if you only modify the list during application startup.